# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/appname.app/appname

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios8

I submitted my iOS app today and got a validation warning:

```
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/appname.app/appname: booleanValue, setPreview
```

I want to know what is this problem?, this warning doesn't prevent me to upload the app.

I have had no problems before this release and I haven't added new frameworks, only new code written by me.

I have Xcode6 and the app is build for iOS8.

Comment: upload it. don't take tension

Comment: Now it's getting warning like "The app references non-public selectors in payload/appname.app/appname: viewport"

Comment: i have upload 2 times with this warning and my app never rejected. i think ur app rejected for some another issues. try to find in apple resulation center they explained cleary what is the actual issues of rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload it, I've recently uploaded version with warnings like this, and it was accepted.
Seems Apple has some bugs in Private API detection algorithms.

Comment: We uploaded with same issues. Apple Rejected it. And after we removing facebook and google sdk in my project and resubmitted without any warning. They approved this version. Now we are in situation to use FB and GOOGLE compulsorily...

Comment: that was probably issue with `ASIdentifier` not booleanValue or setPreview

Comment: This warning occur when i'm trying to add Google Integration related file and frameworks...